# iozone re-write on FUSE very slow when file is bigger than cache

Tags: io, fuse, iozone

In my IO benchmark a FUSE based file system with iozone. I notice the re-write was much slower than write when the file size is bigger than memory. Why re-write is relied on cache and is it possible to bypass re-write test?